# What is the correct way to change an indice's stemmer on Elasticsearch when using magento

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I have a Magento 2 site with product titles and descriptions in Portuguese, that uses  Elasticsearch as the catalog search engine. When I search for terms with accents the search results quality is very poor. Taking a stab at the issue I found out that magento creates the indices with an english stemmer, which is not appropriate for my case, as seen in the following image:

[image]

I know I can change the stemmer to be in portuguese, via direct manipulation on elasticsearch, but upon each `magento indexer:reindex` the old indice is deleted and a new one is created again with english, so that would not be a feasible solution.

Further digging into the issue I found that there's an `esconfig.xml` in the `Magento_Elasticsearch` module which is base to `Magento_Elasticsearch6`, with the following structure

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Elasticsearch:etc/esconfig.xsd">
    <stemmer>
        <type>stemmer</type>
        <default>english</default>
        <de_DE>german</de_DE>
        <en_US>english</en_US>
        <es_ES>spanish</es_ES>
        <fr_FR>french</fr_FR>
        <nl_NL>dutch</nl_NL>
        <pt_BR>portuguese</pt_BR>
    </stemmer>
    <stopwords_file>
        <default>stopwords.csv</default>
        <de_DE>stopwords_de_DE.csv</de_DE>
        <en_US>stopwords_en_US.csv</en_US>
        <es_ES>stopwords_es_ES.csv</es_ES>
        <fr_FR>stopwords_fr_FR.csv</fr_FR>
        <nl_NL>stopwords_nl_NL.csv</nl_NL>
        <pt_BR>stopwords_pt_BR.csv</pt_BR>
    </stopwords_file>
</config>
```

I wonder what is the proper way to override this file as to make Magento use a portuguese stemmer  by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think No need to override any file.

Try below with the default system configuration, Magento does provides such a setting.

Stemmer works on the value configured on the store level.

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to **Stores** > Settings > **Configuration** and switch to the specific store view if the website has multiple store views.
2. In the left panel under **General**, choose **General**.
3. Expand Expansion selector the **Locale Options** section
4. unchecked `Use Website` if exists and Set Locale to the store language to **Portuguese (Brazil)** or **Portuguese (Portugal)** as per your convenience.
5. Save config and clear cache if needed.

Run the catalog search index command - `php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

For more info,
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/locale-options.html#to-set-the-store-locale

Comment: After doing this the stemmer still remains as english.

Comment: It should work unless some custom module changes.